# Vercel + Express, can't seem to get any complex paths working

Tags: node.js, express, serverless, vercel

I've been trying to get a GraphQL API up and running on Vercel using Express. I've managed to get my main API working under the `/api` endpoint without many problems by doing this:

```
app.use(
  '/api',
  graphqlHTTP(async (req, res) => ({
    schema,
    context: createContext({ req, res }),
    graphiql: true,
  })),
)
```

This exposes the API as well as a [graphql playground](https://serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate-pj6a12zq7-creativiii.vercel.app/api) without any problems

So I then tried do expand it with other non-graphql endpoints for OAuth purposes, but no matter what I do I can't seem to access those endpoints once the API is deployed.

If I try to register:

```
app.get('/api/testing', (req, res) => res.json({ foo: 'bar' }))
```

I will get the correct response when developing locally, but once it's deployed [I get a 404](https://serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate-pj6a12zq7-creativiii.vercel.app/api/testing).

I've made the repository public, the server file can be found [on Github](https://github.com/coloredcat/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/blob/feature/express-passport/api/index.ts).

Anyone know what's going on? Why aren't any endpoints but the one located at `/api` working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on [this](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel) page about using Express with Vercel.
You have to add vercel.json to the root of your project with this content:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/api" }]
}
```

then you can use:

```
app.get("/api/some/path", (req, res) => {
  res.send("wow, it actually worked");
});
```